# LINQ statement causes sub to terminate without exception

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012

I'm building a database app. I created the tables in SSMS and used the EntityFramework NuGet add-in for VS2012 to create my data objects. Up until now, everything was working great. When I try to write LINQ statements for one particular data object the sub simply exits at the LINQ statement. In the following code, db is my database context:

```
private void FillPayRate()
{
    var payRate = db.PayRates.SingleOrDefault(p => p.AgeGroupID == m_ageGroupID &&
    p.SystemID == m_systemID && p.PositionID == m_positionID);
    if (payRate != null)
        txtPayRate.Text = payRate.Rate.ToString("0.00");
    else
        txtPayRate.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

When the program runs that sub, it exits at the first statement. No exception, no error, no nothing. It's as if that statement is being interpreted as `return;` The app just continues to run, but the rest of the code in the sub, and any code in a sub that called that sub, is skipped.

All of my other data objects and data access models work just fine. I've checked the database to make sure that the appropriate records exist. I've tried replacing the first statement with all of the following:

```
var payRate = (from t in db.PayRates
               where t.AgeGroupID == m_ageGroupID &&
                     t.SystemID == m_systemID &&
                     t.PositionID == m_positionID
               select t).FirstOrDefault();

var payRate = db.PayRates.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PayRateID == 1);

var payRate = db.PayRates.ToArray();

var payRate = db.PayRates.FirstOrDefault();
```

Each statement produces the same behavior.

I've completely deleted the project bin and obj folders and rebuilt it. I've also checked the data object model and map and everything matches up properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you just do `db.PayRates.FirstOrDefault()` (with no predicate)? What about `db.PayRates.ToArray()`?

Comment: Rebuild the project.  Be sure it wipes out the PDB files.

Comment: Is it executing in a Task?

Comment: @GarryVass I'm sorry, I'm not sure I know what you mean by that? This sub runs when the user has selected an item in the last of 3 different list boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this fixed, although I still have no idea what caused the problem in the first place. I deleted the whole models folder and had the Entity Framework plugin recreate all of the models and maps, and then I re-did all of the custom object properties from scratch. It was tedious (which is what I was hoping to avoid), but it worked.

Thank you all for your suggestions, and I'm sorry that we couldn't figure out what was happening so that this could be useful for anyone else.